# Partial Application - Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript, partial-application

I am reading Eloquent Javascript and am having a difficult time understand the example below. Would anyone be able to do a line by line type explanation? Specifically, I'm confused as to why the first loop is starting at one, and why the push method is being used on both knownArgs and arguments. I know that this is related to "partial application", but would like a more detailed explanation of what exactly is happening line by line.

```
var op = {
 "+": function(a,b){return a + b;}
};

function partial(func) {
 var knownArgs = arguments;

 return function() {
  var realArgs = [];

  for (var i=1; i<knownArgs.length; i++)
   realArgs.push(knownArgs[i]);

  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
   realArgs.push(arguments[i]);

  return func.apply(null, realArgs);
 };
}

map(partial(op["+"], 1), [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);
```

Comment: It took me _literally_ 2 seconds to find this http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821. Read all about it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up. Hopeful I can still get an explanation for the above.

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more explanation.  As it happens, I just taught a couple of JavaScript classes with some examples very similar to this, only a couple weeks ago :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `knownArgs` variable keeps a copy of the value of `arguments` as it was when `partial()` was called. That call returns *another* function, and inside that code `arguments` are a whole different list — they're the arguments passed to that returned function. In other words:

var p = partial(someFunction, "hello", "world");

When `p()` is called, `knownArgs` will be "hello" and "world" (well and `someFunction` too but note that the first loop starts at 1). If the call to `p()` looks like this:

p("how", "are", "you");

then it will first push "hello" and "world" onto the `realArgs` list (from `knownArgs`), and then the three parameters passed to `p()`, from `arguments`.

*edit* — step-by-step breakdown of how `map(partial(op["+"], 1), [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);` is evaluated:

1. First, `op["+"]` has to be evaluated. I'm guessing it returns a function, probably something like this:

   ```
   function add(a, b) {
     return a + b;
   }
   ```
2. That "add" function and the value `1` are passed to `partial()`.  Thus inside `partial()` the `arguments` pseudo-array looks like

   ```
   [ add, 1 ]
   ```

   That is, the first parameter is the "add" function from `op["+"]` and the second is that value `1`.  The only thing that `partial()` really does before returning the anonymous function is to save `arguments` into `knownArgs`.  That has to be done because the weird `arguments` pseudo-variable is *always* assigned a new value upon each and every function call. It's being preserved here so that the code in the anonymous function can access it later.
3. Now, with the anonymous function returned from `partial()` and that array of even numbers, we call `map()`.  That function probably looks something like this (I don't have the book):

   ```
   function map(fn, list) {
     var i, result = [];
     for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
       result.push( fn( list[i] ) );
     }
     return result;
   }
   ```

   Inside `map()`, then, the first parameter is the anonymous function returned from the earlier call to `partial()`.  What does that function do?  Well, it combines the parameters from the original `partial()` call — *except the first one* — with the parameters passed into it.  The `map()` function only passes one parameter, so the resulting parameter list on each call to the anonymous function will be the value `1` passed to `partial()` and then, on each iteration, a different even number from the list.

A simpler example would be to consider what happens when you call:

```
partial(op["+"], 1)(2);
```

That is, if you call `partial()` and then immediately use its return value (the anonymous function).  The effect will be the same as calling:

```
add(1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand your answer and it's relation to the code above. I'm still pretty fuzzy it seems on the concept of partial application. Besides the link posted by elclanrs do you have any recommendations on an explanation for someone completely new to programming?

Comment: @KMcA well for someone new to programming this is some fairly fancy stuff :-)  It's not really hard though; it's just a set of ideas you have to work with in order to get familiar with it. Starting off with JavaScript is a great idea because it's a relatively friendly environment for playing with concepts like this. The key thing is that, in JavaScript and some other languages, functions are not just blobs of code, but also objects, and can be treated pretty much like any other object. They simply have the additional feature of being callable as functions!

Comment: I've been considering using this as a stopping point in this book since it seems I'm learning some advanced concepts, yet I'm know where near a point where'd I'd actually use these concepts. When you say "fancy stuff", would you say that I might be better off backing up and doing some intro to programming books/online courses? I have "Learn to Program" for example sitting here on my desk, but hate stopping Eloquent Javascript without finishing.

Comment: Well actually writing code and experiencing the ways in which things go wrong (and right) is, in my opinion, essential. I don't think you should worry about damaging yourself with advanced stuff however :-)  Seriously though the most important thing to do is find some not-too-big projects and work on them.  I wish I could suggest books or websites that would be good for that purpose, but I don't really know of any. (I used the Project Euler site to learn Erlang, but those can be tricky (or impossible :-) and sadly JavaScript is not the best language for that.)

Comment: Still stewing over this. I set up alerts to see the values being added with each loop. I'm a very visual learner so I like to actually picture what's happening. Can you elaborate visually how the call to map(partial(op["+"], 1), [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]); is actually being applied. I see the big picture and it all makes perfect sense, but what I'm having a difficult time "seeing" is how "1" and the array are being applied. Because I'm so visual, I see "partial(func)" and I'm not able to "see" the connection to "1" and the array. Any additional help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @KMcA I'll edit the answer with a step-by-step description of what happens.  (I'll make an assumption of what `map()` does; it's probably the typical functional programming meaning of "map".)

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the map and add functions but you were correct. I think I have a much better handle on this now. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop starts at one instead of zero because `knownArgs[0]` contains the function, not its argument.

`push` appends a single element to an array. It's a fairly common way to build an array.

```
  var realArgs = [];

  for (var i=1; i<knownArgs.length; i++)
    realArgs.push(knownArgs[i]);

  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
    realArgs.push(arguments[i]);
```

will create a new array concatenated from `knownArgs` and `arguments`. `knownArgs` holds the curried arguments and the function (which is not appended to `realArgs`), and `arguments` are the arguments supplied to the function when it's being called.