# jQuery Validate - how to run function inside "required" without executing it on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Very simple example when I use function inside 'required' that should run on actual form validation but it also does execute on load of the page.

The question is how to avoid it and make so it would call other function inside required only on actual validation.

```
$("form").validate({           
            rules : {
                testinput: {
                    required: runFunction('hello world')
                }
});

function runFunction(a){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your function call inside another function:

```
$("form").validate({           
    rules : {
        testinput: {
            required: function(el) {
                runFunction('hello world')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The reason for this is because the value returned from `runFunction` is being set as the value of the `required` property on load. With the above code you are assigning a function to the `required` property which will only be run when validating.

Comment: I see, in that case do you think I could avoid adding extra function for each input and just validate a group of them like:

$("input[name=testinput],input[name=testinput2],input[name=testinput3]").each(function(){
       $(this).rules("add", {
          required: function(element){runFunction('hello world')}
       });   
     });

Comment: That method should work too, although I don't see the issue with keeping the rules all together in the `validate()` initialisation.

Comment: Thank you, the only issue is that I have way too many input and that would look like:
testinput:{required: function(el) {runFunction('hello world')}}
testinput2:{required: function(el) {runFunction('hello world')}}
testinput3:{required: function(el) {runFunction('hello world')}}
testinput4:{required: function(el) {runFunction('hello world')}}
etc.

Comment: Is the variable passed in (the `hello world` in your example) different for each input? If not you could simply do `testinput: { required: runFunction }` and then declare the variable within the function.

Comment: ok thank you, last question just as you might know. Why the console always returns 'HELLO WORLD' twice? is this something the plugin does?

Comment: That one I don't know. Is that while using the code in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Call function in `required callback` like,

```
$("form").validate({           
    rules : {
        testinput: {
             required: function(){ runFunction('hello world'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Read [required-method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)

Answer (score 1):

another way would be using some sort of partial application

see maybe: [Partial Application - Eloquent Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335600/partial-application-eloquent-javascript)

your code might then be something among this lines:

```
$("form").validate({           
    rules : {
        testinput: {
            required: partial(runFunction,'hello world')
        }
});
```

Where `partial(runFunction,'hello world')` creates a new function which is eqivalent to runFunction('hello world').

This a powerfull concept from functional programming, and JS can be extended to support such a thing.

EDIT: [1](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821) might be a better explanation of partial application

http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821